# Expected a type, but has kind ‘* -> Constraint’

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a calculator to add and subtract numbers. I have two abstractions here, an `Expr`, which is modeled as a tree, and a typeclass `Operand`, which comprise the left and right nodes of the tree. Operands have a function `combine` that apply a function to the left and right nodes:

```
module Data.Calculator where

class Operand a where
    combine :: a -> a

data Operator = Plus | Minus
data Expr = Node Operator Operand Operand | Value Integer

instance Operand Expr where
    combine (Node op left right) =
        case op of 
            Plus -> (combine left) + (combine right)
            Minus -> (combine left) - (combine right)
    combine (Value a) = (Value a)

instance Num Expr where
    (+) (Value left) (Value right) = Value (left + right)
    (*) (Value left) (Value right) = Value (left * right)
    abs (Value a) = Value (abs a)
    fromInteger i = Value i
    negate (Value a) = Value (negate a)
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error

```
calculator/src/Data/Calculator.hs:7:35: error:

    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Operand’
      Expected a type, but ‘Operand’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
    • In the type ‘Operand’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘Node’
      In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
  |
  | data Expr = Node Operator Operand Operand | Value Integer
```

What does this mean? I'm aware that this problem can be solved without defining Operand as a typeclass, but I'd like to use the `Operand` typeclass, since that is a subject I'm learning about now. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Expecting one more argument to ‘Operand’
  Expected a type, but ‘Operand’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’`

Comment: Please see the edits

Comment: Weakly realted: you defined a typeclass `Operand`. Do you expect to have at least two instances `instance Operand T1` and `instance Operand T2` for two distinct types `T1,T2`? If you think you will only use `Operand Expr`, this is a sign that you should not be using a typeclass, but simply define `combine :: Expr -> Expr`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I suspect that you're thinking in terms of object-oriented programming, with `combine` as a member function of the base class `Operand` and `Expr` inheriting from `Operand`. Type classes are not like OO classes – in particular, they're not types.

Answer (score 7):

In your code `Operand` is not a type, but *class* of types. There can be no values of type `Operand`, because it's not a data type. Therefore, you can't use it as part of the definition of `Expr`.

The cryptic notation `* -> Constraint` means that the identifier `Operand`, if applied to a type (denoted `*`), will give you a `Constraint`. The compiler says that it expected a type in that context (such as `Int` or `String` or `Maybe Float`, etc.), but you gave it `Operand`, which has kind `* -> Constraint`.

From your code, I'm guessing what you actually meant to do was to construct `Expr` in such a way that it can contain values of *any* types, as long as those types have an instance of `Operand`. Would that be a correct assumption?

If so, then the way to do that is to wrap those values in an existential type:

```
data SomeOperand = forall a. Operand a => SomeOperand a
```

Or same thing in GADT notation:

```
data SomeOperand where
    SomeOperand :: forall a. Operand a => a -> SomeOperand
```

These notations literally say that type `SomeOperand` wraps exactly one value `a`, which must have an instance of `Operand`.

Now you can use `SomeOperand` in the definition of `Expr`:

```
data Expr = Node Operator SomeOperand SomeOperand | Value Integer
```

Now, when matching on `Expr`, you'll get a value that has an instance of `Operand`, and so you'll be able to apply `combine` to it:

```
f :: Expr -> Expr
f (Node op (SomeOperand a) (SomeOperand b)) = Expr op (combine a) (combine b)
f (Value i) = Value i
```

Notice that you can't really do anything with such operands except convert them to other values of the same type, which again leaves you nowhere. In order for this to be useful in any way, the class `Operand` must have some methods for converting to something other than the type itself, for example:

```
class Operand a where
    combine :: a -> a
    showOperand :: a -> String
```

Now I can use `showOperand` to a useful end:

```
showExpr :: Expr -> Expr
showExpr (Node op (SomeOperand a) (SomeOperand b)) = showOperand a ++ show op ++ showOperand b
showExpr (Value i) = show i
```